# Issue with Uploading Cover Photo for Lead Generation Form using PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I'm experiencing an issue with the Facebook PHP SDK when trying to upload a cover photo for a lead generation form. Despite following the SDK documentation and examples, I keep encountering this error

```
(#100) Param cover_photo must be a file with one of the following types: image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png. Received file of type 'application/octet-stream'.
```

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
$data = array_filter(
     array(
         LeadgenFormFields::NAME => $task['name'],
         LeadgenFormFields::QUESTIONS => $task['questions'],
         LeadgenFormFields::FOLLOW_UP_ACTION_URL => $task['followUpActionUrl']
         )
);

if (isset($task['coverPhotoUrl'])) {
    // Code to download and save the image to a temporary file
    $tmpFile = FacebookHelper::getTemporaryFileWithName($contentUrl, $name);
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($contentUrl);
    
    if (file_put_contents($tmpFile["filename"], $fileContent) === false) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to write the cover photo to temporary file: " . $tmpFile["filename"]);
    }

    // Passing the file path directly
    $data["cover_photo"] = $tmpFile["filename"];
}

$page = new Page($task["facebookPageId"]);
$leadForm = $page->createLeadGenForm([], $data);
```

The issue persists even after ensuring the file is correctly downloaded and exists. I've tried using CurlFile and directly passing the file path, but neither approach works. CurlFile approach was throwing "operation aborted by callback" error.

The SDK's method `createLeadGenForm` is used for this operation.

Could you please provide guidance on the correct approach to upload a cover photo using the PHP SDK? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like the issue is that the URL you are requesting, gets a response with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`, which the SDK method used to fetch this, doesn't like. But if all you need to pass in `$data["cover_photo"]` is a local file path, you should be able to use a different method to get the image data from the URL, stored into your file system - file_get_contents, cURL, etc.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your answer. In my implementation, I am using file_get_contents to fetch the image data and then writing it to a local file. This approach should be independent of the Content-Type of the original response, as it simply saves the binary data to a file.

The challenge seems to be with the Facebook PHP SDK's handling of the file during the upload process, rather than the method of fetching the image. The local file is correctly downloaded and saved, and its path is passed to the SDK, which should be the correct approach for file uploads as far as I seen in examples.

Comment: I don't know where it raises that error, my suspicion was that `FacebookHelper::getTemporaryFileWithName` would be doing that. Which in case you are already handling the the download yourself using file_get_contents, seems superflous to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe You are correct that the `FacebookHelper::getTemporaryFileWithName` might seem redundant since I'm already handling the file download with file_get_contents. The purpose of using it is to generate a temporary file path where the downloaded image can be saved. The error seems to occur during the file upload process via the SDK, not during the file download or saving process. I believe the issue is more about how the SDK or the underlying cURL operation handles the file upload.

Comment: _"The purpose of using it is to generate a temporary file path where the downloaded image can be saved."_ - that's something https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php can do for you just as easily.

Comment: _"The error seems to occur during the file upload process via the SDK, not during the file download or saving process."_ - but if _all_ you are sticking into your data object you pass to the upload process, is `$data["cover_photo"] = $tmpFile["filename"];`, then I don't see how it _could_ possibly determine any content-type from that - if that really _is_ a file system path, and not a URL.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for the `tempnam` tip. You're right; the `$tmpFile["filename"]` is indeed a file system path, not a URL.  My understanding is that the SDK should handle this path and manage the necessary headers (including Content-Type) during the upload process. Facebook documentation doesn't have any examples to how to handle uploads. Here SDK source code: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/main/src/FacebookAds/Object/Page.php#L1634 Also doesn't give any tip about file uploads.

Comment: The TypeChecker the data gets passed to only does a `file_exists` check for the `file` parameter type (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/main/src/FacebookAds/TypeChecker.php#L79) - so I suppose it is save to assume, that this indeed _wants_ a file system path.

Comment: What does the `$tmpFile["filename"]` value you got there actually look like, I suppose this probably doesn't contain any file suffix, that would match the file type? If the SDK later on tries to determine the mime type for this file _based on_ a file name suffix, that could explain why it only comes up with a generic `application/octet-stream` then. If that is the case here, can you try what happens when you pass a path to a file that _does_ have a proper suffix?

Comment: @CBroe The `$tmpFile["filename"]` does include a file suffix. Typically looks like: `/tmp/fb_5f3e3c1d6c9e4.jpg`

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to debug into the SDK code a bit deeper, to find where it actually tries to determine that mime type. Maybe it uses `mime_content_type` or `finfo_file`, and those aren't able to determine the type correctly on your system.